# Retrieve a selection of drop down list in php

Tags: php, sql

I retrieved the selection of drop down from database. Now, I want to edit the entries. When I open the page for edit, I should have the selected data of drop down displayed in the page.

I used the following code to populate the drop down list.

```
<?php

    try {
        $sql1 = "select vehicleno from vehicle";
        $projresult = $dbh->query($sql1);                       
        $projresult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {   
        die("Some problem getting data from database !!!" . $e->getMessage());
    }

    echo '<select name="vehicleno"  id="vehicleno" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->vehicleno);?>>';


    $vno=$_POST['vehicleno'];


    while ( $row = $projresult->fetch() ) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['vehicleno'].'">'.$row['vehicleno'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. Do you want the dropdown to submit to another page/same page when you change it?

Comment: a `select` element does not have a `value` attribute

Comment: where is the `edit` page?

Comment: My question is, how shall I retrieve the selection of this drop down, which is stored in backend using a edit page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the value of a select box directly in html, therefore as you loop through the options you'd have to check if that is the option selected. For example...

```
echo '<select name="vehicleno"  id="vehicleno" class="form-control" required';

$vno = $_POST['vehicleno'];

while ( $row = $projresult->fetch() ) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['vehicleno'] . '"' . ($vno == $row['vehicleno'] ? 'selected' : '') . '>'.$row['vehicleno'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

If this was your parent page and you wanted to send the value to a subpage such as edit-vehicle.php then you'd have to use a form element...

```
echo '<form action="edit-vehicle.php" method="post"><select name="vehicleno" id="vehicleno" class="form-control" required';

$vno = $_POST['vehicleno'];

while ( $row = $projresult->fetch() ) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['vehicleno'] . '"' . ($vno == $row['vehicleno'] ? 'selected' : '') . '>'.$row['vehicleno'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select></form>';
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp for more about php form handling.